# NSData PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsmutabledata

Every time I try and open an image within an App I get the following errors:

### : ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk

### : ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk

### : ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk

Here is my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>


@interface ImageViewController : UIViewController<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>{
    dispatch_queue_t background;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) PFObject *message;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableData *imageData;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSURLConnection *connection;
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;

@end
```

Here is the implementation:

```
#import "ImageViewController.h"

@interface ImageViewController ()

@end

@implementation ImageViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"ImageViewController starts here");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
        PFFile *imageFile = [self.message objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
        NSURL *imageURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:imageFile.url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:imageURL];
    self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
    [self.connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [self.connection start];
    
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if (self.imageData == nil){
        self.imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        [self.imageData appendData:data];
    }
    
    
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData];
    
}

@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not actually appending anything but the initial chunk to the imageData object right now, hence the corrupt PNG.

Change this

```
if (self.imageData == nil){
    self.imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [self.imageData appendData:data];
}
```

To this

```
if (self.imageData == nil){
    self.imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}
[self.imageData appendData:data]; // <-- moved outside conditional
```

Comment: Note that you should actually initialize `self.imageData` in `connection:didReceiveResponse:` since multiple responses may be received per request, for example, in the case of an HTTP Redirect response.  In that case, your "image" data will have any data in the redirect message prepended to your image data, again yielding an invalid image.